# Why do I get an error when I'm trying to query a child property in NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent

I seem to get an error when querying an object that has a child POCO property object:

```
could not resolve property: PreferredLanguage.Name of: AcademyData.Entities.StudentsInformation
```

My query:

```
Session.QueryOver<StudentsInformation>().Where(x => x.Active == 1 && x.PreferredLanguage.Name == firstName).List()
```

If I remove the x.PreferredLanguage.Name criteria, it works, and I see the correct Name value of the object, but it won't let me use it as a query. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my mapping:

```
    References(x => x.PreferredLanguage).Column("PreferredLanguageID");
```

Also, I've split my POCO's and mappings into 2 seperate assemblies, if that makes any difference. I configure the mapping so:

```
.Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AcademyData.Dummy>().AddFromAssemblyOf<data.core.Dummy>())
```

Ignore the dummy, was using it to test something.

EDIT: I've tested it using an entity from the same assembly and the problem still exists. 
EDIT:

### I found a solution to my problem:

```
return SessionManager.Session.QueryOver<StudentsInformation>().JoinQueryOver<PersonBase>(s => s.Person).Where(p => p.FirstName == firstName).List();
```

Is this the right way of doing it, or should I still be able to do it without the JoinQueryOver for a different table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use LINQ instead of QueryOver:

```
return Session.Query<StudentsInformation>()
              .Where(x => x.Active == 1 && x.PreferredLanguage.Name == firstName)
              .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join on the child entity if you wish to query by that child entity.  That is the correct way of doing it.  You could also use `JoinAlias` if you wish.